# Creating Bat file from inno setup file

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I   have an   inno setup code which works fine. Can anyone tell me how to make a bat file from an inno setup code so that a single click will initiate the installation set up.I have done that for java class files.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An Inno Setup installer is directly executable (it's a standard .exe). You can already just double-click it to start the installer. Are you trying to directly run the `.iss` file instead of compiling it into a `Setup.exe`?

Comment: @KenWhite I have compiled the code, from where I can have the .exe file for the iss source code .Sorry I am a beginer to this.

Comment: You find it where you told you script to put it, in the `[Setup]` section, using the `OutputDir` entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need for a `.bat` file. `Inno Setup` creates a stand-alone executable (by default named `Setup.exe`) that you can simply double-click like any other Windows executable.

The executable it creates is nameable either by renaming the `Setup.exe` to a different name (`YourAppSetup.exe`, for instance) manually, or by using the `OutputBaseName` value in the `[Setup]` section. You can control where the setup executable is created by using the `[Setup]` section value `OutputDir`. Here's an example, from the `CodeExample1.iss' sample provided in your`Inno Setup` installation:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={code:MyConst}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
InfoBeforeFile=Readme.txt
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output
```

This creates the default `Setup.exe` in the `userdocs:` (your `My Documents` folder), in a subfolder named `Inno Setup Examples Output`. To put it somewhere else, just change the `OutputDir` entry to a different location. For instance, to put it in a sub-directory of your source folder named `Installer`, just use

```
OutputDir=Installer
```

For more info, see the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/), in the `Setup Script Sections->[Setup] Section Directives` branch.

To change the name from `Setup.exe` to something else, add a new entry:

```
OutputBaseName=MyAppSetup
```